# CDK Menu Offset

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

It is possible to set an offset to the trigger with the CDK overlay (e.g. `cdkConnectedOverlayOffsetY`). However, I could not find a similar feature in the CDK menu documentation. Is there a way to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can always add a "class" -in the mat-menu indicate "class", e.g. called custom

```
<mat-menu [aria-label]="item.menu" class="custom">
```

Then, in your styles.css (should be in a global style) indicate

```
.mat-menu-panel.custom
{
  margin-left:20px
}
```

Really it's enought if the class is called `.custom`, but I like use `.mat-menu-panel.custom` to be more especific.

There another way. Mat-menu add the class 'mat-menu-before','mat-menu-after','mat-menu-above' and/or 'mat-menu-below' to the menu depending the position (the two first are related to position X, and the two last are related to postion Y)

So you can (again in styles.css) use some like

```
.custom.mat-menu-below {
  margin-top: 30px; //this makes that our "custom" menu,
                    //if appears below appears 30px below
}
```